# Add(remove) element(s) from an ImmutableSortedMultiset

Tags: java, collections, guava

I am struggling how to perform basic operations using a Guava ImmutableSortedMultiset...

- How would one create a copy of an existing ImmutableSortedMultiset that is contains a new element?
- How would one create a copy of an existing ImmutableSortedMultiset where one of the elements has been removed?

If possible, I would like to be able to perform these operations *without* sorting the existing collection each time a new element is added(removed).

Comment: You cannot do it without sorting the existing collection.  (Though I suppose the sort is likely to be O(n) for the case of just one different element, which is as good as you're going to get anyway.)

Comment: This is *not* the use case immutable collections are designed for, to be clear.  You're looking for persistent collections.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks for the tip.  I will google about for persistent collections.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Could you perhaps construct the collection of objects you need in an `ArrayList` and then copy them into an `ImmutableSortedMultiset` once you need them to be sorted and counted? Could you use a `HashMultiset` as the temporary structure if a `List` won't do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it without rebuilding a new ImmutableSortedMultiset. Assuming you have an `original` multiset, I would start by making a composite view using the methods in `Multiset`:

```
// View with one more element
Multiset<String> view = Multisets.union(original, ImmutableMultiset.of("a"));
```

or

```
// View with one less element
Multiset<String> view = Multisets.difference(original, ImmutableMultiset.of("a"));
```

followed by creation of the immutable sorted copy:

```
ImmutableSortedMultiset<String> copy = ImmutableSortedMultiset.copyOf(view);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a tricky question because as far as I know Guava doesn't provide any easy method to achieve your goal. Maybe you shouldn't be dealing with immutable collections if you need to change them. For example, you can store your data in mutable SortedMultiset and make a defensive copy when you need to pass it somewhere

However, these operations are still possible.

**Add and copy**

In order to add element in immutable collection, you need to use builder

```
ImmutableSortedMultiset<T> original = ...; //your original data which you want to modify
T element = ...; //new element which you want to add
ImmutableSortedMultiset<T> result = ImmutableSortedMultiset.<T>naturalOrder()
                                     .addAll(original) //copying original data
                                     .add(element)
                                     .build();
```

**Remove and copy**

Here things get a little bit harder because you will need to filter original collection and exclude element which you want to remove

```
ImmutableSortedMultiset<T> original = ...;
T el = ...; //element which you want to remove
ImmutableSortedMultiset<T> result = ImmutableSortedMultiset.copyOf( //copy...
                                 Collections2.filter(original,   //and filter
                                 Predicates.not(Predicates.equalTo(el)));
```

You will have to wrap this into a method to make it easier to use.

However, I highly advise you to use mutable collections instead of immutable if you really need to modify them.

Comment: Note that your remove version removes _all_ elements equal to `e1` and not just one. Remember that we are working with a Multiset!